# android ddms tool error

Tags: android-emulator

i got the error in ddms tools.

when i run the ddms in android sdk tools it shows"Failed to get the adb version": cannot run program adb;crate process error=2;the system cannot find the file specified".

Answer (score 0):

Try add to the PATH variable the sdk tools path. 
it should looks like 'C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\' (don't forget the last backslash).